# Drupal 7. Дополнительные данные о пользователе.

Tags: drupal, php

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно реализовать дополнительные данные о пользователе в виде "один ко многим", т.е. пользователь заполняет анкету - идентификатор анкеты сохранился, еще раз заполнил - сохранился еще один идентификатор. Я так понимаю, что управления полями тут не подойдут. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как рациональнее всего решить эту задачу?

Comment: Скорее всего, такой функционал надо пилить руками.

Comment: Хотя нет. Кажется, есть модуль. Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [этот](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_revision) модуль должен делать, то что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

судя по всему вам просто нужна сущность Анкета с полями. Анкетами пользователя будут все ноды с типом Анкета у которых автором является этот пользователь, то есть этот список легко вывести используя Views

создайте тип материала Анкета (profile) с полями, а заполнением анкеты будет ссылка на создание такой ноды /node/add/profile

так же стоит рассмотреть модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2